# Support ListFragment issue

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-listfragment, android-support-library

I'm currently using a ListFragment together with an ExpandableListView to show some data backed by a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter. Everything works fine, but I recently switched to the support.v4 package, to make use of the ViewPager class to swipe between tabs. Swiping and all the other classes that now use the support.v4.Fragment work fine, but my ListFragment has stopped working.

There are no exceptions thrown, but the ListFragment simply doesn't show any items.

This is the code for the ListFragment:

```
public class VisuTextFragment extends ListFragment {

    private Storage mStorage;
    private int mFilterSensortype;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mStorage = Storage.newSQLiteDatabase(getActivity());
        mFilterSensortype = -1;
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.l_visu_text, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        fillData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.textvis, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_filter:
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setTitle("Filter by sensor type");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.l_dialog_filter);

            Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.filter_ok);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                int filter = Integer.parseInt(((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_filter)).getText().toString());
                    mFilterSensortype = filter;
                    fillData();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.filter_cancel);
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
            dialog.show();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        fillData();
    }

    public void fillData() {
        Log.d("VisuTextFragment", "fillData()");
        Cursor cursor;
        if (mFilterSensortype == -1)
            cursor = mStorage.queryAllAsCursor();
        else
            cursor = mStorage.query(mFilterSensortype);

        TextVisCursorAdapter adapter = new TextVisCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                cursor,
                R.layout.l_visu_text_group,
                new String[] { Storage.ELEMENT_ID, Storage.ELEMENT_ENTRIES_DATE, Storage.ELEMENT_ENTRIES_LATITUDE, Storage.ELEMENT_ENTRIES_LONGITUDE, Storage.ELEMENT_ENTRIES_SENSORTYPE },
                new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.date, R.id.latitude, R.id.longitude, R.id.sensortype },
                R.layout.l_visu_text_child,
                new String[] { Storage.ELEMENT_MEASUREMENTS_VALUE },
                new int[] { R.id.value });

        ListView lv = (ListView) getListView();
        ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) lv;
        elv.setGroupIndicator(null);
        elv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

And this is the layout that I'm using (don't know if that helps):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/id"/>
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="@string/date"/>
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="@string/latitude"/>
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="@string/longitude"/>
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/sensortype"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_entries"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Just FYI: The TextView's in the layout file are shown, but the list itself is just missing. Not even the TextView for an empty list is shown.

Hope you can help.

EDIT: I have checked for the `ExpandableListView`'s width and height via their corresponding methods and both return a value of 0. Its `getCount()` method returns 347. So the View definitely exists and is filled properly, but it is for some weird reason just not drawn to the screen.

EDIT2: Ok I fixed the problem. The problem was that the `LinearLayout` that hosted the `TextViews` on top of the actual list had its `layout_height` attribute set to `fill_parent`, which strangely was no issue for the non-support version as well as the composer in eclipse, since they both worked that way and I didn't even notice that it was set to `fill_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that that its butter to use android:id="@android:id/list" instead of android:id="@+id/android:list", also, in your case its really useless to extend ListFragment, just use Fragment and use findViewById for your expandableList.

Can you change:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }
```

to:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle aSavedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(aSavedInstanceState);
fillData();
    }
```

make sure that your fillData method is called.

Comment: Yes i used @android:id/list before and then saw @+id/android:list somewhere else and tried it to see if it makes any difference. I am still using ListFragment, so it automatically switches between the list itself and the "empty"-view if there is no data.

Comment: Just to be sure I extended from Fragment instead of ListFragment but the problem is still there.

Comment: can you confirm that your are seeing the @string/no_entries, in fact you are using fill_parent in the first LinearLayout ?

Comment: Look at the edit, already fixed the problem. Indeed the problem was fill_parent. Thx for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

`getListView()` in a `ListFragment` is specifically looking for a listview id of `@id/android:list`.  I'm not sure that adding the "+" in there like you did would have an effect or not, but it's the first thing I would try.

You also note you switched to the support library... did you switch all the appropriate method calls?  For example, instead of `getFragmentManager` you would need to use `getSupportFragmentManager` and instead of using an `Activity` to control the fragments, you would need to use `FragmentActivity`, etc.

Comment: Yes I switched to `FragmentActivity`. I also deleted all imports and re-imported them to see if there is any support class that i could use instead of the normal ones. To be honest i don't think it has something to do with the id of the ListView. I have tried any possible way to write it and everything is giving me the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed the problem. The problem was that the LinearLayout that hosted the TextViews on top of the actual list had its layout_height attribute set to fill_parent, which strangely was no issue for the non-support version as well as the composer in eclipse, since they both worked that way and I didn't even notice that it was set to fill_parent.